# How do I highlight particular counties within states?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I highlight particular counties within states?

```
states <- map_data("state")
south_coast <- subset(counties, region %in% c("texas", "oklahoma", "kansas"))
ggplot(data = south_coast) + 
  labs(title="Southern Plains of US",subtitle = "Plague positive counties") +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill=region, group = group), color = "black") + 
  coord_fixed(1.2) + 
  guides(fill=FALSE)+theme_bw()
```

Comment: Please improve the example code. You define `states` but then don't use it, and you use `counties` but don't define it.

Comment: south_coast <- subset(states, region %in% c("texas", "oklahoma", "kansas"))
southplains<-subset(counties, subregion %in% c("lubbock","dallas"))
ggplot(data = southplains) + 
  labs(title="Southern Plains of US",
       subtitle = "Plague positive counties")+
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat,fill=subregion, group=group), color = "white") + 
  coord_fixed(1.2) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  theme_bw()

Comment: I'm still not seeing where `counties` comes from.

Comment: I am new in R. Would you help me out with how to do it? I need to highlight some counties from these 3 states.